# Why the R class in android is not static?

Tags: android

Why the R class in android is not static? when it contains all static content.

```
public final class R {
//static content
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Java language policies, A top level public class cannot be static. And when you dive deep into the usage of static class you will find it is used to create independent inner class that does not hold anonymous reference of outer class. Therefore the purpose and use of static keyword before class is completely different.

**non-static inner class**

```
class A
{
   int var1;
   class B{
     int calc(){
       // can access A.var1 directly
      }
   }
}
```

**static inner class**

```
class A
{
   int var1;
   static class B{
     int calc(){
       // cannot access A.var1 directly, need object to be passed
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

R.java is the dynamically generated class, created during build process to dynamically identify all assets (from strings to android widgets to layouts), for usage in java classes in Android app. Note this R.java is Android specific (though you may be able to duplicate it for other platforms, its very convenient), so it doesn't have much to do with Java language constructs.

android.R.java is not just where XML ids are stored. It also contains access to resources - such as drawables, layouts, strings, arrays, and basically anything you can declare in resources.

Personally I find that it is useful when using Eclipse. I can simply type findViewById(R.id. and Eclipse will show a tooltip with a list of options to choose from.

However at a platform level, I would say that the hardcoded id variables help prevent errors when using Strings to identify resources -- something that can be debuggable while programming (or during compilation, rather than runtime).